# limit $A_n = \{s : 0 < s \le \frac{1}{n}\}$. What is the limit of $A_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, elementary-set-theory

I'm working my way through some practice problems (no solutions given) for an upcoming exam, and I came across the following problem:

Let $A_n = \{s : 0 < s \le \frac{1}{n}\}$. What is the limit of $A_n$? What would the limit be if instead $A_n = \{s : 0 \le s \le \frac{1}{n}\}$?

My thinking is that in both cases, $A_n$ is a monotonically decreasing series because as we choose larger and larger $n$ values, the possible values for $s$ decrease. Earlier in the book, they claim that such a series has $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. So, is that the limit, or do I need to take it further? I'm also not sure how the limit of the series would change based on the fact that 0 is/isn't a possible value in the sequence. Any hints or insights would be appreciated.

Comment: You are mistaken in taking the union, you need to take the intersection.

Comment: Yes, sorry. LaTeX slip up. Fixed now.

Comment: Assume the limit is not empty and apply the Archimedian property to get a contradiction (for the first case).  The Archimedian property says that the infinum of $ \{ \frac12, \frac13, \dots \} $ is zero.  For the second case, the limit is $ \{ 0 \} $.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NickR. I never really knew about the Archimedian property, but I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we afirm that $\lim A_{n} = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n} = \emptyset$ (in the first case). Suppose that intersection was not empty. Then it would exist an $x \in A_{n}$ for every natural $n$ , which means that $x>0$ and $x\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for every $n$. Can you see why this is an absurd?

For the second case, you can show in a similar manner that $\lim A_{n} = \left\{ {0} \right\}$.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I could have arrived at those answers if I plugged $\infty$ into both the first and second case. Is that a method for solving these types of limit problems, or not? Also, why is the limit of the second case a set and not a number?